# Moment of Inertia of a Rectangular Parallelepiped

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

Moment of inertia calculated about an edge for a rectangular parallelepiped is given by
$$I = (m/3) (a^2 + b^2), $$
my question is:
when m(a^2+b^2) is added to I, the new value obtained is Moment of Inertia about what axis?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

> when m(a^2+b^2) is added to I, the new value obtained is Moment of Inertia about what axis?

This looks like a homework/quiz question so I will just give a small hint: check *parallel axis theorem*, also known as *Steiner theorem*.